# Logstash grok filter for collectd metrics data

Tags: logstash-grok, grok

I'm processing some metrics data and store them into Elasticsearch. Now I want to get those data from Elasticsearch and apply a filter on them, the goal is to have more relevant fields after the logstash filtering. For this purpose, I planed to use a grok filter. But I'm not a grok expert and I never parsed this kind of data.

This is a sample data coming from Elasticsearch:

```
{
      "_index" : "metrics",
      "_type" : "metrics",
      "_id" : "AVh4R8n3cN8PY7B3sFIM",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "event_time" : "2016-11-18T16:31:59.769Z",
        "message" : "[{\"values\":[0.04,0.18,0.17],\"dstypes\":[\"gauge\",\"gauge\",\"gauge\"],\"dsnames\":[\"shortterm\",\"midterm\",\"longterm\"],\"time\":1479486719.645,\"interval\":10.000,\"host\":\"test-host\",\"plugin\":\"load\",\"plugin_instance\":\"\",\"type\":\"load\",\"type_instance\":\"\"}]",
        "version" : "1",
        "tags" : [ ]
      }
}
```

After logstash filtering I expect to have this:

```
{
      "_index" : "metrics",
      "_type" : "metrics",
      "_id" : "AVh4R8n3cN8PY7B3sFIM",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "event_time" : "2016-11-18T16:31:59.769Z",
        "values" : [0.04,0.18,0.17],
        "dstypes" : ["gauge","gauge","gauge"],
        "dsnames": ["shortterm","midterm","longterm"],
        "time" : 1479486719.645,
        "interval" : 10.000,
        "host" : "test-host",
        "plugin" : "load",
        "plugin_instance" : "",
        "type" : "load",
        "type_instance" : ""
      }
}
```

Can someone help me by giving advices or sample grok filter to achieve this?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved that issue by using another filter. grok was not appropriate for this use case.

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}
```

The json filter extract exactly each data from message array as a json of key value pair. and that solve the issue.